# How to call continue on loop from within dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

This is more of a curiosity question. Interested to know if we can call a function like `continue` from a dictionary value in order to skip an iteration

```
example_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

dict_function = { 3 : continue }

for val in example_list:
 dict_function[val]()
 print(val)
```

Looking for something like the following to be output

```
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `continue` is not a function, it is a statement.

Comment: No. `continue` is a statement. It can only be used inside of the context of a loop.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware - I was wondering if there was a function that could do what continue does

Comment: Not sure what warranted the downvote

Comment: You'll learn to live with the downvotes. Our answers received one each as well:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` is a language construct, not a function. Take a look at the disassembled byte code:

```
import dis
dis.dis('for _ in range(5): continue')
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              23 (to 26)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 9 (to 25)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (_)
             19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   25 POP_BLOCK
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

See the `19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE`? That's what `continue` is *actually* translated into. You cannot "call" it as you would a normal function.

---

Try something like this:

```
dict_function = { 3 : False }

for val in example_list:
    if not dict_function.get(val, True):
        continue
```

Use the key's value to decide whether you skip that iteration or not, and then actually skip it.

Comment: Although was looking for something a little more sophisticated - I think other folks looking for a quick implementation would be quite happy with this response - thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible?

No. `continue` is a syntactic construct. A statement, it cannot be called. It can only be used in the context of a loop. Being used anywhere else will result in a `SyntaxError`. There is no function that could replicate the behavior of `continue` because it requires context of the surrounding loop, as @coldspeed's answer shows.

A possible workaround would perhaps be to set a flag. If the flag is a certain value, then you would jump:

```
example_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  
flags = {3 : True}

for val in example_list:
   if flags[val]:
       continue
```

Of course, the above solution assumes you'll have `flags` entries for all of the other possible values in `example_list`. Otherwise, you'll get a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I came up with that does what you want is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# From:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928441/how-to-call-continue-on-loop-from-within-dictionary-value


class Continue(Exception):  pass
def do_continue():  raise Continue


example_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

dict_function = {3:do_continue}

for val in example_list:
    try:
        if val in dict_function:
            dict_function[val]()
        print(val, end=' ')
    except Continue:  pass
```

Output:

```
1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Here's what's going on:

1. We define a Continue exception whose sole purpose is to be caught at the end of a loop.
2. We create a do_continue() function whose sole purpose is to throw said exception.
3. We populate the dict_function with the (3,do_continue) key,value pair.
4. We wrap the body of the main loop in a try/catch block, doing nothing if the Continue exception is caught.
5. In the try block, we check to make sure the val exists in dict_function, and if so, execute it.